# I want to post only date in database but i want to get date and current time in database in same column

Tags: php

I want to post the only date in the database but I want to get the date and current time in the database in the same column get the date value but time is zero display.

Answer (score 1):

Post date time both using  `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` function